# Filled pdf forms are (sometimes) not properly displayed

Tags: pdf, latex, evince

I have produced a fillable pdf form in LaTeX. Now, I am receiving filled out versions of that form, but a few of the submissions are not displayed in a readable way: Letters are scrambled or only a few letters are display. This happens both with evince and okular, under Ubuntu 16.04.

From the problematic files, it may be possible that they were produced on Macbooks, but I am not certain about that. Under Windows 7, Acrobat Reader displays the problematic forms without any issues

What are potential reasons for this and how can I properly view the forms without switching to Windows every time?